# Compare multiple anova models to find the best model

Tags: r, regression, lm, anova

I'm running multiple models thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71808497/running-anova-on-multiple-column-condition) where they explained me how to run it using multiple combination.

This is how the summary of my models look like.

a

```
                                      Length Class Mode
PC1 ~ Sex                             5      anova list
PC2 ~ Sex                             5      anova list
PC3 ~ Sex                             5      anova list
PC4 ~ Sex                             5      anova list
PC5 ~ Sex                             5      anova list
PC6 ~ Sex                             5      anova list
PC7 ~ Sex                             5      anova list
PC8 ~ Sex                             5      anova list
PC1 ~ fAge                            5      anova list
PC2 ~ fAge                            5      anova list
PC3 ~ fAge                            5      anova list
PC4 ~ fAge                            5      anova list
PC5 ~ fAge                            5      anova list
PC6 ~ fAge                            5      anova list
PC7 ~ fAge                            5      anova list
PC8 ~ fAge                            5      anova list
PC1 ~ Index                           5      anova list
PC2 ~ Index                           5      anova list
PC3 ~ Index                           5      anova list
PC4 ~ Index                           5      anova list
PC5 ~ Index                           5      anova list
PC6 ~ Index                           5      anova list
PC7 ~ Index                           5      anova list
PC8 ~ Index                           5      anova list
PC1 ~ Lane                            5      anova list
PC2 ~ Lane                            5      anova list
PC3 ~ Lane                            5      anova list
PC4 ~ Lane                            5      anova list
PC5 ~ Lane                            5      anova list
PC6 ~ Lane                            5      anova list
PC7 ~ Lane                            5      anova list
PC8 ~ Lane                            5      anova list
PC1 ~ Gen                             5      anova list
PC2 ~ Gen                             5      anova list
PC3 ~ Gen                             5      anova list
PC4 ~ Gen                             5      anova list
PC5 ~ Gen                             5      anova list
PC6 ~ Gen                             5      anova list
PC7 ~ Gen                             5      anova list
PC8 ~ Gen                             5      anova list
PC1 ~ Sex + fAge                      5      anova list
PC2 ~ Sex + fAge                      5      anova list
PC3 ~ Sex + fAge                      5      anova list
PC4 ~ Sex + fAge                      5      anova list
PC5 ~ Sex + fAge                      5      anova list
PC6 ~ Sex + fAge                      5      anova list
PC7 ~ Sex + fAge                      5      anova list
PC8 ~ Sex + fAge                      5      anova list
PC1 ~ Sex + Index                     5      anova list
PC2 ~ Sex + Index                     5      anova list
PC3 ~ Sex + Index                     5      anova list
PC4 ~ Sex + Index                     5      anova list
PC5 ~ Sex + Index                     5      anova list
PC6 ~ Sex + Index                     5      anova list
PC7 ~ Sex + Index                     5      anova list
PC8 ~ Sex + Index                     5      anova list
PC1 ~ Sex + Lane                      5      anova list
PC2 ~ Sex + Lane                      5      anova list
PC3 ~ Sex + Lane                      5      anova list
PC4 ~ Sex + Lane                      5      anova list
PC5 ~ Sex + Lane                      5      anova list
PC6 ~ Sex + Lane                      5      anova list
PC7 ~ Sex + Lane                      5      anova list
PC8 ~ Sex + Lane                      5      anova list
PC1 ~ Sex + Gen                       5      anova list
PC2 ~ Sex + Gen                       5      anova list
PC3 ~ Sex + Gen                       5      anova list
PC4 ~ Sex + Gen                       5      anova list
PC5 ~ Sex + Gen                       5      anova list
PC6 ~ Sex + Gen                       5      anova list
PC7 ~ Sex + Gen                       5      anova list
PC8 ~ Sex + Gen                       5      anova list
PC1 ~ fAge + Index                    5      anova list
PC2 ~ fAge + Index                    5      anova list
PC3 ~ fAge + Index                    5      anova list
PC4 ~ fAge + Index                    5      anova list
PC5 ~ fAge + Index                    5      anova list
PC6 ~ fAge + Index                    5      anova list
PC7 ~ fAge + Index                    5      anova list
PC8 ~ fAge + Index                    5      anova list
PC1 ~ fAge + Lane                     5      anova list
PC2 ~ fAge + Lane                     5      anova list
PC3 ~ fAge + Lane                     5      anova list
PC4 ~ fAge + Lane                     5      anova list
PC5 ~ fAge + Lane                     5      anova list
PC6 ~ fAge + Lane                     5      anova list
PC7 ~ fAge + Lane                     5      anova list
PC8 ~ fAge + Lane                     5      anova list
PC1 ~ fAge + Gen                      5      anova list
PC2 ~ fAge + Gen                      5      anova list
PC3 ~ fAge + Gen                      5      anova list
PC4 ~ fAge + Gen                      5      anova list
PC5 ~ fAge + Gen                      5      anova list
PC6 ~ fAge + Gen                      5      anova list
PC7 ~ fAge + Gen                      5      anova list
PC8 ~ fAge + Gen                      5      anova list
PC1 ~ Index + Lane                    5      anova list
PC2 ~ Index + Lane                    5      anova list
PC3 ~ Index + Lane                    5      anova list
PC4 ~ Index + Lane                    5      anova list
PC5 ~ Index + Lane                    5      anova list
PC6 ~ Index + Lane                    5      anova list
PC7 ~ Index + Lane                    5      anova list
PC8 ~ Index + Lane                    5      anova list
PC1 ~ Index + Gen                     5      anova list
PC2 ~ Index + Gen                     5      anova list
PC3 ~ Index + Gen                     5      anova list
PC4 ~ Index + Gen                     5      anova list
PC5 ~ Index + Gen                     5      anova list
PC6 ~ Index + Gen                     5      anova list
PC7 ~ Index + Gen                     5      anova list
PC8 ~ Index + Gen                     5      anova list
PC1 ~ Lane + Gen                      5      anova list
PC2 ~ Lane + Gen                      5      anova list
PC3 ~ Lane + Gen                      5      anova list
PC4 ~ Lane + Gen                      5      anova list
PC5 ~ Lane + Gen                      5      anova list
PC6 ~ Lane + Gen                      5      anova list
PC7 ~ Lane + Gen                      5      anova list
PC8 ~ Lane + Gen                      5      anova list
PC1 ~ Sex + fAge + Index              5      anova list
PC2 ~ Sex + fAge + Index              5      anova list
PC3 ~ Sex + fAge + Index              5      anova list
PC4 ~ Sex + fAge + Index              5      anova list
PC5 ~ Sex + fAge + Index              5      anova list
PC6 ~ Sex + fAge + Index              5      anova list
PC7 ~ Sex + fAge + Index              5      anova list
PC8 ~ Sex + fAge + Index              5      anova list
PC1 ~ Sex + fAge + Lane               5      anova list
PC2 ~ Sex + fAge + Lane               5      anova list
PC3 ~ Sex + fAge + Lane               5      anova list
PC4 ~ Sex + fAge + Lane               5      anova list
PC5 ~ Sex + fAge + Lane               5      anova list
PC6 ~ Sex + fAge + Lane               5      anova list
PC7 ~ Sex + fAge + Lane               5      anova list
PC8 ~ Sex + fAge + Lane               5      anova list
PC1 ~ Sex + fAge + Gen                5      anova list
PC2 ~ Sex + fAge + Gen                5      anova list
PC3 ~ Sex + fAge + Gen                5      anova list
PC4 ~ Sex + fAge + Gen                5      anova list
PC5 ~ Sex + fAge + Gen                5      anova list
PC6 ~ Sex + fAge + Gen                5      anova list
PC7 ~ Sex + fAge + Gen                5      anova list
PC8 ~ Sex + fAge + Gen                5      anova list
PC1 ~ Sex + Index + Lane              5      anova list
PC2 ~ Sex + Index + Lane              5      anova list
PC3 ~ Sex + Index + Lane              5      anova list
PC4 ~ Sex + Index + Lane              5      anova list
PC5 ~ Sex + Index + Lane              5      anova list
PC6 ~ Sex + Index + Lane              5      anova list
PC7 ~ Sex + Index + Lane              5      anova list
PC8 ~ Sex + Index + Lane              5      anova list
PC1 ~ Sex + Index + Gen               5      anova list
PC2 ~ Sex + Index + Gen               5      anova list
PC3 ~ Sex + Index + Gen               5      anova list
PC4 ~ Sex + Index + Gen               5      anova list
PC5 ~ Sex + Index + Gen               5      anova list
PC6 ~ Sex + Index + Gen               5      anova list
PC7 ~ Sex + Index + Gen               5      anova list
PC8 ~ Sex + Index + Gen               5      anova list
PC1 ~ Sex + Lane + Gen                5      anova list
PC2 ~ Sex + Lane + Gen                5      anova list
PC3 ~ Sex + Lane + Gen                5      anova list
PC4 ~ Sex + Lane + Gen                5      anova list
PC5 ~ Sex + Lane + Gen                5      anova list
PC6 ~ Sex + Lane + Gen                5      anova list
PC7 ~ Sex + Lane + Gen                5      anova list
PC8 ~ Sex + Lane + Gen                5      anova list
PC1 ~ fAge + Index + Lane             5      anova list
PC2 ~ fAge + Index + Lane             5      anova list
PC3 ~ fAge + Index + Lane             5      anova list
PC4 ~ fAge + Index + Lane             5      anova list
PC5 ~ fAge + Index + Lane             5      anova list
PC6 ~ fAge + Index + Lane             5      anova list
PC7 ~ fAge + Index + Lane             5      anova list
PC8 ~ fAge + Index + Lane             5      anova list
PC1 ~ fAge + Index + Gen              5      anova list
PC2 ~ fAge + Index + Gen              5      anova list
PC3 ~ fAge + Index + Gen              5      anova list
PC4 ~ fAge + Index + Gen              5      anova list
PC5 ~ fAge + Index + Gen              5      anova list
PC6 ~ fAge + Index + Gen              5      anova list
PC7 ~ fAge + Index + Gen              5      anova list
PC8 ~ fAge + Index + Gen              5      anova list
PC1 ~ fAge + Lane + Gen               5      anova list
PC2 ~ fAge + Lane + Gen               5      anova list
PC3 ~ fAge + Lane + Gen               5      anova list
PC4 ~ fAge + Lane + Gen               5      anova list
PC5 ~ fAge + Lane + Gen               5      anova list
PC6 ~ fAge + Lane + Gen               5      anova list
PC7 ~ fAge + Lane + Gen               5      anova list
PC8 ~ fAge + Lane + Gen               5      anova list
PC1 ~ Index + Lane + Gen              5      anova list
PC2 ~ Index + Lane + Gen              5      anova list
PC3 ~ Index + Lane + Gen              5      anova list
PC4 ~ Index + Lane + Gen              5      anova list
PC5 ~ Index + Lane + Gen              5      anova list
PC6 ~ Index + Lane + Gen              5      anova list
PC7 ~ Index + Lane + Gen              5      anova list
PC8 ~ Index + Lane + Gen              5      anova list
PC1 ~ Sex + fAge + Index + Lane       5      anova list
PC2 ~ Sex + fAge + Index + Lane       5      anova list
PC3 ~ Sex + fAge + Index + Lane       5      anova list
PC4 ~ Sex + fAge + Index + Lane       5      anova list
PC5 ~ Sex + fAge + Index + Lane       5      anova list
PC6 ~ Sex + fAge + Index + Lane       5      anova list
PC7 ~ Sex + fAge + Index + Lane       5      anova list
PC8 ~ Sex + fAge + Index + Lane       5      anova list
PC1 ~ Sex + fAge + Index + Gen        5      anova list
PC2 ~ Sex + fAge + Index + Gen        5      anova list
PC3 ~ Sex + fAge + Index + Gen        5      anova list
PC4 ~ Sex + fAge + Index + Gen        5      anova list
PC5 ~ Sex + fAge + Index + Gen        5      anova list
PC6 ~ Sex + fAge + Index + Gen        5      anova list
PC7 ~ Sex + fAge + Index + Gen        5      anova list
PC8 ~ Sex + fAge + Index + Gen        5      anova list
PC1 ~ Sex + fAge + Lane + Gen         5      anova list
PC2 ~ Sex + fAge + Lane + Gen         5      anova list
PC3 ~ Sex + fAge + Lane + Gen         5      anova list
PC4 ~ Sex + fAge + Lane + Gen         5      anova list
PC5 ~ Sex + fAge + Lane + Gen         5      anova list
PC6 ~ Sex + fAge + Lane + Gen         5      anova list
PC7 ~ Sex + fAge + Lane + Gen         5      anova list
PC8 ~ Sex + fAge + Lane + Gen         5      anova list
PC1 ~ Sex + Index + Lane + Gen        5      anova list
PC2 ~ Sex + Index + Lane + Gen        5      anova list
PC3 ~ Sex + Index + Lane + Gen        5      anova list
PC4 ~ Sex + Index + Lane + Gen        5      anova list
PC5 ~ Sex + Index + Lane + Gen        5      anova list
PC6 ~ Sex + Index + Lane + Gen        5      anova list
PC7 ~ Sex + Index + Lane + Gen        5      anova list
PC8 ~ Sex + Index + Lane + Gen        5      anova list
PC1 ~ fAge + Index + Lane + Gen       5      anova list
PC2 ~ fAge + Index + Lane + Gen       5      anova list
PC3 ~ fAge + Index + Lane + Gen       5      anova list
PC4 ~ fAge + Index + Lane + Gen       5      anova list
PC5 ~ fAge + Index + Lane + Gen       5      anova list
PC6 ~ fAge + Index + Lane + Gen       5      anova list
PC7 ~ fAge + Index + Lane + Gen       5      anova list
PC8 ~ fAge + Index + Lane + Gen       5      anova list
PC1 ~ Sex + fAge + Index + Lane + Gen 5      anova list
PC2 ~ Sex + fAge + Index + Lane + Gen 5      anova list
PC3 ~ Sex + fAge + Index + Lane + Gen 5      anova list
PC4 ~ Sex + fAge + Index + Lane + Gen 5      anova list
PC5 ~ Sex + fAge + Index + Lane + Gen 5      anova list
PC6 ~ Sex + fAge + Index + Lane + Gen 5      anova list
PC7 ~ Sex + fAge + Index + Lane + Gen 5      anova list
PC8 ~ Sex + fAge + Index + Lane + Gen 5      anova list
```

This is how the model was calculated with different predictors and Principal components

```
iv <- c("Sex", "fAge", "Index", "Lane", "Gen")  
dv <- paste0('PC', 1:8)
rhs <- unlist(sapply(1:length(iv), function(m) apply(combn(iv, m = m), 2, paste, collapse = ' + ')))
frms <- with(expand.grid(dv, rhs), paste(Var1, Var2, sep = ' ~ '))

models <- lapply(frms, function(x) anova(lm(x, data = mrna.pcs)))
names(models) <- frms
```

Now what i have read so far is the models are compared to find the best possible model that explains the variability. So here with such huge number of models. Given the no of combination I have like here 248 models. So what is the way to compare all these model together and choose those which pass certain threshold such as p value.

For example here two models

```
models[["PC1 ~ Sex"]]
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: PC1
           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
Sex         1 205562  205562  599.57 < 2.2e-16 ***
Residuals 186  63770     343                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> models[["PC2 ~ Sex"]]
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: PC2
           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Sex         1   1098 1097.65  1.1003 0.2956
Residuals 186 185549  997.57
```

If i consider the p-value i can see the first model is significant where as with the same explanatory variable with second the PC2 that is not significant.

So the third model here with the same explanatory variable it is significant.

```
models[["PC3 ~ Sex"]]
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: PC3
           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
Sex         1   6023  6023.0  19.775 1.496e-05 ***
Residuals 186  56650   304.6                      
---
```

Now my idea or rather the crude idea is how to compare those models which are significant for example in the models which I gave above I would compare model 1 and model 3 where there is significance but not model 2 which doesn't have any significance.

In this case I have 248 model , so how to filter and compare the models.

Any help or suggestion would be really appreciated

Comment: Normally one uses statistical tests to compare models they have the same left hand side and different right hand sides.  Since that is not the case here perhaps just calculate the R^2 for each model and forget about statistical tests.

Comment: PC1 ~ Sex  and PC1 ~ Lane  "same left hand side and different right hand sides"  is it possible to compare these ?

Comment: It is not a statistical test but you could use AIC or you could compare each to the model that has both predictors or to the model that has only an intercept.